# Download older android SDK for Qt

Tags: java, android, qt

I have a QML thing that I want to compile for Android.

According to this link https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues I need to use an older version of the SDK.

However, when running `./android` I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "Loading Sources" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                                                                                                 
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(JceSecurityManager.java:65)                                                                                                                                                   
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2610)                                                                                                                                                          
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2634)                                                                                                                                                           
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(CipherSuite.java:602)                                                                                                                                              
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(CipherSuite.java:574)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:460)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:1074)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:354)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(SSLContextImpl.java:42)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:590)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1848)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1824)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:202)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openWithHttpClient(UrlOpener.java:369)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openUrl(UrlOpener.java:188)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:298)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:681)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:603)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetchXmlUrl(AddonsListFetcher.java:272)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetch(AddonsListFetcher.java:137)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsListInTask(PackageLoader.java:465)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.access$200(PackageLoader.java:52)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$3.run(PackageLoader.java:435)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:140)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView.startTask(ProgressView.java:162)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressViewFactory.start(ProgressViewFactory.java:46)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsList(PackageLoader.java:432)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$1.run(PackageLoader.java:238)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:130)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:118)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't read cryptographic policy directory: unlimited
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:324)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:73)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:109)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:106)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:105)
        ... 41 more

(Android SDK Manager:5997): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 70 was not found when attempting to remove it

(Android SDK Manager:5997): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 832 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

And I can't use it to download any SDK.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: looks like you hit a bug here. https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/101 try to use workaround